# Remove a character that is between 2 characters in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe without headers.

It is possible to remove only the | that is between two "" using python? I need to apply the changes to the entire dataframe because it might be on different columns.

It has | as a column delimiter end the column end has 27x |.

Example of rows in the file:

```
Details|145|Sam's Garden|Retail|12.0|"It's a nice | garden"| USD|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Details|200|That's my thing|Retail|23.4|"Not so | great"|EUR|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

I need to remove the | from "It's a nice | garden" and from "Not so | great"

Tried:

`df = df.replace(r'".*?"', lambda m: m.group().replace("|", ""), regex=True)` but it doesn't work.

So no one has a solution but everyone is giving minus to my question...opening the csv with | as delimiter does not work! I basically need to apply a regex syntax to output this `Details|14|retail|"What's new here"|USD|||||||||||||||||||||||||||` from this `Details|14|retail|"What's new | here"|USD|||||||||||||||||||||||||||`

There are all the details needed, no working answer but still everyone gives minus...

Comment: If it is a CSV, just read it in with correct options, why remove the valid chars? `|` is the delimiting char, `"` are quoting chars.

Comment: shouldn't you rather read your file with `|` as separator? `read_csv` will handle the quoted `|` correctly

Comment: It will need to use it after as a file with no extension as input on an app, the fact that it has | as delimiter and between "" has | again, it will error because it will see too many columns, that's why I need to delete the | which is between those ""

Comment: @mozway it will error as pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 2, saw 161

Comment: `pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv', delimiter='|', header=None)`.

Comment: @9769953 the same error as for mozway's solution

Comment: @Corralien answered there, that doesn't work also, but here I am asking how to remove that | if I would have a dataframe already

Comment: I'm not getting any error with your example data. Given the "expected 2 fields" error message, please check that your example data is correct.

Comment: "everyone gives minus": that is because your question is unclear (see the tooltip on the downvote): your problem/error is not reproducible with the example data: using a "|" as delimiter works fine. (Well, two people downvoting is certainly not "everyone". In fact, you do get responses, so work with that and ignore the downvotes.)

Comment: Agree, but I am just trying to find something like "([|])" as a regex pattern...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem if I understood your question right:

I assume this

```
Details|145|Sam's Garden|Retail|12.0|"It's a nice | garden"| USD|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Details|200|That's my thing|Retail|23.4|"Not so | great"|EUR|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

is the contents of some file(let's a **|** separated csv file, **data.csv** here)

and your desired output should be this:

```
Details|145|Sam's Garden|Retail|12.0|"It's a nice garden"| USD|||||||||||||||||||||||||||

Details|200|That's my thing|Retail|23.4|"Not so great"|EUR|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Here is the way to do that:

```
# read the file
with open('data.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# find the indices of all the occurance of the character(| here)
def find_occurrences(s, ch):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(s) if letter == ch]

# apply the required transformation
transformed_lines = []
for line in lines:
    upper_index = find_occurrences(line, '|')[-28] # as you mentioned, end has 27x |
    lower_index = find_occurrences(line, '|')[-30]
    transformed_lines.append(line.replace(line[lower_index+1:upper_index], line[lower_index+1:upper_index].replace('| ', '')))

# save the transformed data/lines back to the file
with open('transformed_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(transformed_lines)
```

Now, you can read this **transformed_data.csv** using pandas with delimiter(**|**).

I hope this will solve your problem or at least give you some insights.